# Adding dynamic irregular data to area chart causes it to shift

Tags: highcharts

Background:
We have intraday data that we display to a user in a highstock chart.  We only want to show 'trading hours' from 8AM to 4:30PM on our chart, so we create static tickPositions on the chart (every 2 hours during those hours).  We show the user either 2 or 5 days worth of data.  We load the chart with all of the data up to the current date/time and it displays properly.

Issue:
We dynamically are adding data to the chart, but on charts that are not very active (don't have ticks every minute) when we add a point, the chart data shifts.  I have captured this in a video:

http://screencast.com/t/gPbrtpHHGN

Do you know what would be causing this?  On the xAxis, we set the min, max, and tickPositions.  We also set plotLines for a 'divider' between days.

I'm attaching a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jdrozd/t99Zk/ to show what is going on.

If you click on 'Add Data (+1 minute)' it works fine (regular data interval).

If you click on 'Add Data (+10 minute) - Wrong' it does not behave as expected (shifts 
graph).

If you click on 'Add Data (+10 minute) - Right' it behaves as expected.  To get this to work, I added 'null' data points to make the data 'regular'.  I want to avoid having to do this.  I would assume that positioning the ticks and adding the data, would allow the data to line up correctly.

Here's the code to add the data inserting null values:

```
function addDataFixed (delay) {
    for(i=1; i<= delay;i++){
        var val = null;
        var minutesToAdd = maxMinutes + i;
        if(i === delay){
            val = getRandomArbitary(102.95,103.4);
        }
        var date = new Date(2013,1,11);
        date.setHours(14);
        date.setMinutes(minutesToAdd);
        var pointData = [date.getTime(),val];
        chart.series[0].addPoint(pointData,false);
    }
    chart.redraw();
    maxMinutes += delay;                
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In Highstock/Highcharts you can't just take actual grouped data and set data with that options - there is a lot of custom properties needed to work. You can simply take `chart.series[0].options.data` to get all points and then set data, see: http://jsfiddle.net/t99Zk/9/

Another solution is (if you really need to use grouped data) loop through all points, and create new array of x and y (either [x, y] or {x: x, y: y}).

Comment: Ok, I was originally using chart.series[0].addPoint(pointData) to add the point, but it was causing the chart to move. The   Even with your solution, the chart still moves when clicking on the 'Add Data (+10 minute) - Wrong' button.  The 'setData' was just another attempt at trying to get this to work.  Can you see the chart 'move'?  Can I avoid this?

Comment: The problem is with `ordinal` still. You can set `xAxis.ordinal = false` and should work. I thinks it is rather buggy feature you are using via addPoint().

Comment: Because this is intraday data, and this shows two days, there is a reason that ordinal = true (I don't want to see a large gap for non-trading hours).  If you set it to false, the chart looks real bad.